# How to add new module position in Opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: opencart2.x

Please suggest step by step, how can I add a new module position in opencart 2.0.1.1 admin with the default ones?

Comment: Read this - http://www.harnishdesign.net/blog/2014/10/09/how-to-set-layout-position-of-module-in-opencart-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

Your new module will be displayed on **Home > Modules** page. Now click on the **green** 
button next to your module to install it. Once the page refreshes , click on the **blue** button to edit it.

Enter the details in edit form of module and save it (make sure you set the **Status as Enabled**). Now you'll get the notification like , **"After you have installed and configured a module you can add it to a layout here! "**

Click on the link **"here!"** to redirect the layouts page. On this page you'll see the various layouts. Click edit next to the layout in which you want your new module to be displayed.

You can see the table having columns like: Module , Position , Sort Order

Now click on the **Blue '+'** icon at the right bottom to add your module, new row will be added. now select your module from the dropdown, set the position you want and provide the Sort order.

At last save the changes and thats it.!! you've new module positioned in your layout. just go to layout page and check it will diaply the module.